# How to change a launching image to landscape?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

How to change a launching image to landscape?

I want to set different launching image when device was landscape mode.

so, I made a PNG file (file name : default-LandscapeLeft@2x~iphone.png)

and dragged it in supporting files folder.

and then building and running in device landscape mode.

but I have seen only black screen.
I can't know reason..

I doubt if .plist file was needed to modify..

Please help from advanced guy....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are on an iPhone or iPod, and if your app supports both portrait and landscape mode, then iOS always launches it in portrait mode.  After it is launched, if the device is in landscape mode, then iOS tells your app to autorotate to landscape mode.  This is explained in [*iOS App Programming Guide: Launching in Landscape Mode*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW9).

Comment: Yup. To put it another way, there is no landscape launch image on iPhone/iPod.